# DateTime field failing validation with time included

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My model has a DateTime field:

```
    [UIHint("DateTimeHHMM")]
    public DateTime TimeBooked { get; set; }
```

It is rendered using the EditorTemplate:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime> 

@if ( Model.HasValue ) { 
@Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" , Model.Value ) , new  {     @class = "span3 disabled" } ) 
} 
else { 
@Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" , DateTime.Now ) , new { @class = "span3 disabled" } ) 
}
```

In my view, the syntax is:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeBooked)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeBooked)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeBooked)
    </div>
```

When creating a record in the view, when I click Save with the following in the text box:

```
22/07/2012 18:33:29
```

- I get the validation message:

> The field TimeBooked must be a date.

Is there something wrong with my Model or Editor Template?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: I think this is related to the way dates are handled as invariant culture. What culture are you using? Is it `en`, as in your example?

Comment: Hi- yes, I have <html lang="en"> at the top of my page.  THanks, Mark

Comment: Hi - it appears that the view/model is expecting the date in the format MM/dd/yyyy - although I'm explicityly setting it to dd/MM/yyyy above - is there any way I can force it to use the format I have selected?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the application is running in the proper language (CultureInfo), especially when it comes to date (and number) formats.

You can do this in the web.config file.

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

You should set this to whatever region/country that matches your needs, that way .NET will handle parsing dates and numbers properly.

Comment: Hi - thanks - I tried that, but it still wouldn't allow (eg) 22/07/2012 - I think it must be the editortemplate in some way - when I change the format to yyyy-mm-dd (which isn't as readable) it works ok??!!

Comment: If you put a break-point in the code, what does the value look like in the Request object? What region/country are you using? That date-format doesn't look English.

Comment: Hi - it looks like: #22/07/2012# - my code should be formatting it as dd/MM/yyyy (which is the UK way of showing dates) - I know VS is american, and as such #22/07/2012# is not valid as there is no "month" numbered 22.  I think I may just revert to yyyy-mm-dd - as there's no confusion using that.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've worked with localization/globalization in .NET for years, and I never have problems anymore, so it makes me wonder, no doubt the .NET framework can handle any situation, so the problem must be somewhere in the code.